# How to delete a particular row from database when its corresponding delete link is clicked?

Tags: magento-1.9

I displayed a table from database and created a delete link to every row. I want to delete a particular row when its corresponding link is clicked. Can anyone help me please..

```
<?php
 $model = Mage::getModel('test/test')->getCollection();
 foreach($model as $data)
  {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$data->getTestId().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data->getTitle().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data->getFilename().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data->getContent().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data->getStatus().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data->getCreatedTime().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data->getUpdateTime().'</td>';
    ?>
    <td><a href='#'></a></td>
    <?php
    echo '</tr>';
   }
 ?>
```

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a delete function in your controller. For example if you want to delete from admin panel then your delete function looks like as shown below.

```
public function deleteAction() 
{
    if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0 ) {
        try {
            $model = Mage::getModel('test/test');

            $model->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
            ->delete();

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully deleted'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

Comment: its woirking. thanx for your help buddy.